# Cassandra - Cannot re-add previously dropped counter column

Tags: cassandra, alter-table, cqlsh

I needed to ALTER my TABLE changing counter column to be int.

Table before dropping and adding:

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name> (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    questions_asked counter);
```

In order to do it i tried to DROP the counter column first:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP questions_asked;
```

Than i tried to ADD new column with the same name but this time as int:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD questions_asked int;
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
>   message="Cannot re-add previously dropped counter column
>   questions_asked"

In addition if i'm trying to give new name to the column there i got this error:

> ConfigurationException: Cannot add a non counter column
>   (question_asked) in a counter column family

If i will do this sequence on column with different type - let's say alter drop text and add int it will work fine.

What is the explanation for this behavior? 
Why after drooping the counter column it seems like it still in the memory?

Comment: Tangentially related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14843  It seems DS, instead of fixing bugs, just validates that the condition which caused the bugs doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to change type for `counter` column, or add the new column with not counter type to table with counters.  In Cassandra, table may contain only counter types, or other types, but you can't mix non-counter types with counter types, except the case when the non-counter type values are in the primary key only.

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCountersConcept.html).

Update after getting the table structure:

As per [CASSANDRA-8099](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8099) you can't add column with incompatible type, and `counter` isn't compatible with anything. Regarding the adding with new name - the table is already marked as containing counters, and it couldn't be used with non-counter types.

Why not simply drop a table & recreate with correct structure?

Comment: But i'm dropping it! it should be deleted, not?  I know the issues you wrote and i don't think it is the answer for the question. If you read carefully  you can see that the question is why after dropping the counter column there is still the behavior for the table like i didn't drop anything?

Comment: because you're adding it with non-counter type... Please show the table structure before dropping the column

Comment: I added the table creation. If dropping really drops the column so there shouldn't be any issue with my sequence. You can reproduce it with cqlsh in a minute. Strange behavior.

Comment: Right now i'm dropping and creating but i wanted to understand this issue. I am familiar with the fact we cannot add column incompatible. I can't understand  Why the table is still marked as containing counters (as you wrote) after i'm dropping this column and no counter column left in the table?

Comment: From what I see in the source code, dropping the columns doesn't change the set of flags that were already set on the table, so if you create table with the counter, it will get corresponding value in the `flags` field, and then it's not cleared...

Comment: Thanks. This is the explanation i was looking for. Do you think it is reasonable? Seems like a bug isn't?

Comment: Yes, it could be a bug, but usually you don’t delete all columns of that type... But you can file corresponding JIRA